# Finding the n-th row in Sybase ASE?

Tags: sql, sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to find the n-th row in a sybase database. I'm more familiar with SQL server so I decided to use a with statement but for some reason that's not working in sybase. Could you guys please explain what's wrong with this code:

```
With test AS 
(
  select *, row_number() over (order by M_MAT) as 'row'
  from OM_MAT_DBF
) 
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE row = 2
```

Comment: The term, "not working" is too vague.  What does it mean in this instance?

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'With'.

Comment: Have you looked at the documentation?  `with` and `row_number` are not supported by Sybase.

Answer (score 1):

`with` and `row_number()` are not valid commands in Sybase ASE.

One option is to select your data (or key data) into a temp table, then use that to find the rows you are looking for.

```
set rowcount 13      --Use the row number you are looking for to limit rows returned
select rownumber=identity(10), M_MAT
  into #temp
  from OM_MAT_DBF
  order by M_MAT
set rowcount 0
```

This will create temporary table with rownumbers. Assuming `M_MAT` is a unique field:

```
select * 
  from OM_MAT_DBF
  where M_MAT =
    (
    select M_MAT 
    from #temp where rownumber = 13   --And find your requested row
    )
```

If you plan on selecting more than one row in a transaction, then you can always bypass the `set rowcount` command when creating the temp table.

Comment: How exactly can I select the 3rd row for instance? I tried using your code but it only gives me the first row no matter if i change it from top 2 to top 40

Comment: Hmm..I thought it worked, but now it appears I was mistaken.  Looks like #temp tables is the way to go.  Updating answer.

Answer (score 0):

If its something like you want the nth row of a table based on some column value you can use the following option:

```
select *
from xyz X where 3 > (
    select count(*)
    from xyz
    where C1 > X.C1
)
order by C1
```

This will order the table based on column `C1` and give you the 3rd row

Comment: I don't know why your answer didn't work for me. I've posted a modified answer.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the answser from @Xint0 didn't work for me. I ended modifying it:

```
DROP TABLE #Data go

CREATE TABLE #Data (Datum INT, PRIMARY KEY (Datum))
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES (10)
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES (20)
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES (30)
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES (40)
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES (50)
INSERT INTO #Data VALUES (60)

DECLARE @n INT
SET @n = 4 -- find the n-th value

DECLARE @t INT
SELECT @t = count(*) - @n + 1 FROM #Data
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM #Data X WHERE @t > (
 SELECT count(*)
 FROM #Data
 WHERE Datum > X.Datum
)
ORDER BY Datum
```