# Selecting within group with filtering

Tags: sql, sap-ase

Say I have the following table / data:

```
create table #a(id int, name varchar(2), score int)
go
insert #a values(0, 'a1', 1)
insert #a values(1, 'b1', 0)
insert #a values(2, 'c1', 1)
insert #a values(3, 'd1', 0)
insert #a values(4, 'd2', 1)
insert #a values(5, 'e1', 0)
insert #a values(6, 'e2', 2)
insert #a values(7, 'e3', 1)
insert #a values(8, 'e4', 0)
```

I'd like to select these rows:

```
id name score
1  b1   0
2  c1   1
4  d2   1
6  e2   2
```

Criteria:

- Only id > 0
- Groups by first letter of the name
- In each group, the highest score
- Tie-breaker, the highest name (ASCII-sorted)

This is what I came up with:

```
select id, name, score
into #b
from #a
where id > 0
group by left(name, 1)
having score = max(score)
go
select f.* 
from #b f
left join #b g on left(g.name, 1) = left(f.name, 1) and g.name > f.name
where g.name is null
order by f.name
```

Can this be done better in terms of not using a temp table / two queries / repetition (all these `left`s) and efficiency in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumptions

- `name` is unique

To test the tie-breaker logic we'll add another 'e' row:

```
insert #a values (9,'e5',2) -- same score as the 6/e2/2 record
```

Since SAP(Sybase) ASE has quite a few limitations ...

- no support for the `rank()` function
- no support for the `row_number()` function
- no support for the `offset/limit` clauses
- limited support for `top` clause in sub-queries
- no support for the `order by` clause in sub-queries

... we need to get a little 'creative' (read: this is going to get a bit convoluted)

First thing we'll do is find the max score for each of the single characters where id > 0:

```
select  left(name,1) as name1,
        max(score)   as mscore

from    #a
where   id > 0

group by left(name,1)
order by 1
go

 name1 mscore
 ----- -----------
 b               0
 c               1
 d               1
 e               2
```

Next we'll join this result set with the original table, matching rows based on the first character and score = max(score):

```
select a2.name1,
       a1.name,
       a2.mscore

from   #a a1
join   (select  left(name,1) as name1,
                max(score)   as mscore
        from    #a
        where   id > 0
        group by left(name,1)) a2

on      left(a1.name,1) = a2.name1
and     a1.score        = a2.mscore
and     a1.id           > 0

order by 1,2
go

 name1 name mscore
 ----- ---- -----------
 b     b1             0
 c     c1             1
 d     d2             1
 e     e2             2
 e     e5             2
```

Next we'll address the tie-breaker rule; we can handle this by applying the `max()` function to our `a1.name` column (making sure to add the appropriate `group by` clause):

```
select a2.name1,
       max(a1.name) as mname,
       a2.mscore

from   #a a1
join   (select  left(name,1) as name1,
                max(score)   as mscore
        from    #a
        where   id > 0
        group by left(name,1)) a2

on      left(a1.name,1) = a2.name1
and     a1.score        = a2.mscore
and     a1.id           > 0

group by a2.name1, 
         a2.mscore
order by 1,2
go

 name1 mname mscore
 ----- ----- -----------
 b     b1              0
 c     c1              1
 d     d2              1
 e     e5              2
```

Last part of the puzzle is to tie this final result back to the original table to obtain the id:

```
select a3.id,
       a4.mname  as 'name',
       a4.mscore as 'score'
from   #a a3
join   (select a2.name1,
               max(a1.name) as mname,
               a2.mscore

        from   #a a1
        join   (select  left(name,1) as name1,
                        max(score)   as mscore
                from    #a
                where   id > 0
                group by left(name,1)) a2

        on      left(a1.name,1) = a2.name1
        and     a1.score        = a2.mscore
        and     a1.id           > 0

        group by a2.name1,
              a2.mscore) a4

on     a3.name = a4.mname

order by 1,2
go

 id          name score
 ----------- ---- -----------
           1 b1             0
           2 c1             1
           4 d2             1
           9 e5             2
```

NOTE: Above queries/results verified on SAP(Sybase) ASE 16.0 SP03 PL01.

---

Net result ...

While it's possible to do what's desired with a single query, the coding is a bit convoluted (and likely a bit harder to maintain).

The original code (2 queries and an intermediate temp table) is a bit easier to understand (and likely a bit easier to maintain).

Comment: Wow, great work! Bazinga, my head is like a golf ball after a Spieth drive!!! :)  Yeah, I agree this is a bit convoluted for this use case. It works though :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             row_number() over (partition by left(name, 1)
                                order by score desc, name asc
                               ) as seqnum
      from #a a
     ) a
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

Some versions of Sybase do support `row_number()`, but not all.  You can also do:

```
select a.*
from #a a
where a.id = (select top 1 a2.id
              from #a a2
              where left(a2.name, 1) = left(a.name, 1)
              order by a2.score desc, name asc
             );
```

EDIT II:

Does this work?

```
select a.*
from (select a.*,
             (select top 1 a2.id
              from #a a2
              where left(a2.name, 1) = left(a.name, 1)
              order by a2.score desc, name asc
             ) as comp_id
      from #a a
     ) a
where id = comp_id;
```

That is, is `TOP` allowed in subqueries in the `SELECT`?

Comment: Ty Gordon, unfortunately `row_number` is not valid on Sybase ASE: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21635112/3821009 :( I also don't think `over` is supported.

Comment: @levantpied . . . Some versions of Sybase *do* support `row_number()`.  But I added an alternative.

Comment: Ty! "Some versions of Sybase do support row_number()" Perhaps non-ASE ones? The second solution doesn't work as `top` is not supported in subquery in a where clause...

Comment: @levantpied . . . Hmmmm, that makes the problem much harder.

Comment: Yeah I think the list of Sybase limitations and SQL itself in [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46547552/3821009) is exactly what you are alluding to. Tough luck eh? Thanks anyway! Helpful for MS SQL folks that stumble onto this :)

Comment: @levantpied . . . If `TOP` is allowed in subqueries in the `SELECT`, you might like the second edit.

Comment: Ty! Just tried and... `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'top'.` Of course not, don't forget we are dealing with Sybase here :) +1 from me for the effort though. I guess this is getting too convoluted for what Sybase supports...