# row number to result set of a SQL query (row_number doesn't work)

Tags: sql, sap-ase, sybase-ase15

using dbeaver some custom sybase driver.
row_number doesn't work:

incorrect syntax near 'over'

```
select row_number() over(), name
from table
```

tried also this

```
over (order by (select 1))
over (order by name)
```

tried variables:

select statement that assigns a value must not be combined with data-retrieval operations

```
declare @num int
set @num = 1
select name, @num = @num + 1
from table
cross join (select @num = 1)
```

Thinking about temporary table with primary int key

Comment: What version of Sysbase you are using?

Comment: which of the 4x Sybase RDBMS products (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? SQLAnywhere (and IQ) tend to have more features (eg, windows functions) than ASE

Comment: its Sybase Ase 16.0

Comment: Sybase (now SAP) `ASE` does not have support for windows functions (eg, `row_number()`, `over()`)

Comment: consider reviewing [How to create a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and then come back and update the question; in particular ... DDL for a table, `insert` statements to populate the table, and the expected result set (corresonding to the provided sample `insert` statements)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new temp table with Identity (call it row number) that will enumerate the rows as IDs and then return that table.

```
SELECT rownumber=identity(10), name
  INTO #temp
  FROM table

SELECT * FROM #temp
```

You can experiment with the value passed into Identity as I don't know what it does.

Comment: i already tried also this: over (order by (select 1)), over (order by name) - same error

Comment: i cant use over - it always says incorrect syntax, maybe i have old sybase driver

Comment: @yndingo My apologies, I must have skipped the part where you already tried that. 
Have you tried NUMBER(*) like this?
SELECT NUMBER( * ), name
FROM table
https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbreference/number-function.html
here is more documentation.

Comment: Thank you, cool function. Unfortunately it also doent work. Says incorrect syntax near'\*'. SELECT NUMBER( * ), name.... If i remove number(*) all ok.

Comment: Do you have any other tables joined in that query? In that case you would need to specify like table.* Maybe

Comment: I noticed here that you need to specify Ascending or descending in OVER parameter as such.
OVER(ORDER BY name ASC)
see if that helps?
https://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.sqlanywhere.12.0.1/dbusage/ug-olap-s-51258147.html

Comment: I have also seen NUMBER() used without parameter. 
It would also help to find out what version of Sybase you have.

Comment: Sybase Ase 16.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21633696/finding-the-n-th-row-in-sybase-ase
You can use something similar to the solution here. Create a temp table with Identity(8) that will enumerate the rows as id's but you can call row_number.
I will edit my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

If `name` column has unique names then you can use subquery to get your row numbered as below:

```
Select * from
(
    select (select count(*)+1 from table a where t.idName >a.idName ) row_number, name
    from table t  
)x order by row_number
```

Comment: i have idName as unique. When i use it row_number unfortunately counts from zero. When i use name + id row_number shown are too big, when i use order by row_number in name+idName query is too heavy. It runs 1400sec and doesnt stop

Comment: Re "counts from zero" - can't you just add 1 to it then?

Comment: @yndingo I have revised the query to solve the issue.

Comment: 1. if i call only one field it runs fast. 2. problem begins when calling 2 fields, row_number is not ordered. 3. when call order by row_number script i stopped script after 5 minutes. I cant wait so long 4. i have voted for your answer but unfornately i cant use it

Comment: extremely sorry for that. It would be great if you can share some sample data for better understanding. @yndingo I have added an order by clause. Please check now.

Comment: i need to order by row_number, so i used it and as i said i cant wait so long. I cant share data sorry.

Comment: Got your point @yndingo. Please try my revised answer to get the result in your desired order.

Comment: select * from (select (select count(*)+1 from table a where t.idName>a.idName) as rownum, idName, Name from table t) x order by rownum. Stopped script after 300sec. Without ordering it runs about 5 sec

Comment: It will be `order by row_number` not `order by rownum`

Answer (score 1):

ah. Old question again...
First, ASE didn't suppor the window function like IQ -- eg. this row_number() over ()..
But you can get the similar effect using another ASE's function -- identity(n)
Here's a simple Sample --

```
1> create table #t1(str varchar(5))
2> go
1> insert #t1 values('haha')
2> insert #t1 values('hehe')
3> insert #t1 values('hoho')
4> go
1> select * from #t1
2> go
 str
 -----
 haha
 hehe
 hoho
1> select rownumber=identity(10),str into #t2 from #t1
2> go
(3 rows affected)
1> select * from #t2
2> go
 rownumber     str
 ------------- -----
             1 haha
             2 hehe
             3 hoho

(3 rows affected)
```

Pls be noted -- this function -- identity(n) -- can only be used in "select into" statement, so you need to use it and put the resultset to a temp table then retrieve it with the generated rownumber.
Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select COUNT(*) as number_row, name
from table
```

`COUNT()` is also return number of row
**Try This**

Comment: number_row returns 6046969 and doesnt change... I dont need total rows, just row#1, #2...

Comment: if i use count + distinct + group -> number_row is 1

Answer (score 0):

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) as RowNum, name
from table
```

`OVER()` in that specify one column name and
`AS` is use to set name of column and row column

**Try this**

Comment: i cant use over - it always says incorrect syntax, maybe i have old sybase driver

Answer (score 0):

realized by temporary table:
alter table #tempTable
add id numeric(10,0) identity not null